# When service called, JSON displays fully correct in log, but missing almost all text for consumer

Tags: c#, json, .net, swagger

I have a getStatus RESTful service (implemented using swagger) that takes an ID and returns a JSON object with some header information that is assembled by the service as well as JSON that from multiple tables in an Oracle DB (stored as CLOB with JSON constraint).

I include that information because the JSON that is assembled by the service displays correctly, but all of the data that comes from the DB is not appear to the consumer, though it does in the log. Not all of the data missing is stored as JSON in the DB though.  For example, corCount and errorCount are pulled the DB and assembled the same way that failedCorrs is, but failedCorrs is missing.

- **Code:**

```
app.MapGet("/status/batchId={batchId}", (decimal batchId) => getStatus(batchId));
```

```
object getStatus(decimal id)
{
        JArray docsGeneratedArray = JArray.Parse(getDocsGenJSON(id));

        var statusObj = new
        {
            batchId = id,
            ...
            requests = new List<object>(),
            docsGenerated = docsGeneratedArray
        };


        foreach (RequestObj request in getRequests(id))
        {
            var curRequestObj = new
            {
                requestId = request.id,
                corrCount = request.corrCount,
                errorCount = request.errCount,
                failedCorrs = new List<object>()
            };

            foreach (CorrObj corr in request.corrList.Where(c => c.failed))
            {
                var curFailedCorr = new
                {
                    corrId = corr.id,
                    error = corr.errorMsg

                curRequestObj.failedCorrs.Add(curFailedCorr);
            }
            statusObj.requests.Add(curRequestObj);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statusObj));

        return statusObj;

    }
}
```

- **Output to Consumer:**

```
{
  "batchId": 51286,
  "appName": "CoGSTestApp",
  "corrCount": 3,
  "errorCount": 0,
  "requests": [
    {
      "requestId": "requestId1",
      "corrCount": 3,
      "errorCount": 0,
      "failedCorrs": [
        
      ]
    }
  ],
  "docsGenerated": [
    {
      "outputChannelName": [
        
      ],
      "nextRunTime": [
        
      ],
      "fileCounts": [
        [
          [
            [
              
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "outputChannelName": [
        
      ],
      "nextRunTime": [
        
      ],
      "fileCounts": [
        [
          [
            [
              
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- **Console.WriteLine:**

```
{
  "batchId": 51286,
  "appName": "CoGSTestApp",
  "corrCount": 3,
  "errorCount": 0,
  "requests": [
    {
      "requestId": "requestId1",
      "corrCount": 3,
      "errorCount": 0,
      "failedCorrs": []
    }
  ],
  "docsGenerated": [
    {
      "outputChannelName": "CoGSTestPrint",
      "nextRunTime": "Output Channel is OnDemand, running immediately.",
      "fileCounts": [
        {
          "fileType": "PS",
          "fileCount": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "outputChannelName": "CoGSTestFileShare",
      "nextRunTime": "Output Channel is OnDemand, running immediately.",
      "fileCounts": [
        {
          "fileType": "PDF",
          "fileCount": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing seems to be related to serialization of the JSON data when returning the response to the consumer. The data appears correctly when printed to the console but not when received by the consumer.

The most likely reason for this behavior is that some of the data from the Oracle DB, which is stored as CLOB with JSON constraint, is not being correctly serialized during the response generation. To resolve this issue, you can explicitly deserialize the JSON data from the CLOB before adding it to the `statusObj`.

Here's the modified code with the explicit deserialization:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; // Import the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq namespace

app.MapGet("/status/batchId={batchId}", (decimal batchId) => getStatus(batchId));

object getStatus(decimal id)
{
    var statusObj = new
    {
        batchId = id,
        // ...
    };

    // Code here to pull JSON from DB as a CLOB
    // Let's assume the JSON data from the DB is stored in the variable "jsonFromDb"

    // Explicitly deserialize the JSON data from the CLOB
    JObject dbJsonData = null;
    try
    {
        dbJsonData = JObject.Parse(jsonFromDb);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception if the parsing fails
        // Log the error or take appropriate action
        // For now, we'll just return the original statusObj without the data from the DB
        return statusObj;
    }

    // Add the deserialized data to the statusObj
    statusObj["dataFromDB"] = dbJsonData;

    // Rest of your code ...

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(statusObj));

    return statusObj;
}
```

In the above code, we use the `JObject.Parse` method from the `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` namespace to explicitly parse the JSON data from the CLOB obtained from the Oracle DB. If the parsing is successful, we add the `dbJsonData` object to the `statusObj`. If there's an exception during parsing (e.g., invalid JSON format in the CLOB), we simply skip adding the data from the DB to the `statusObj` and return the statusObj without the DB data.

By explicitly deserializing the JSON data from the CLOB and including it in the response, you should be able to resolve the issue and ensure that the consumer receives the correct JSON data.

Comment: So, the JSON in the DB is actually an array.  I tried doing this:

`JArray docsGeneratedArray = JArray.Parse(batch.DOCS_GENERATED_CLB);`

And then using that in the statusObj, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Sorry for multipl;e comments.  Also, for the missing "failedCorrs", that's actually not even JSON in the DB, but assembled using the DB just like the data that's present for appName, corrCount, etc.  Very confusing.

Comment: 1. Parsing JSON Array: Use `JArray.Parse(batch.DOCS_GENERATED_CLB)` to correctly parse the JSON array from the DB. Make sure `docsGeneratedArray` is populated with the data.
2. Assembling "failedCorrs" Data: Ensure "failedCorrs" is properly structured as JSON. Initialize it as an empty array and populate it using a List. Convert the List to an array when adding it to the requests object.
By correctly parsing the JSON array and assembling"failedCorrs"as valid JSON, the output JSON should contain all necessary data. If problems persist, log intermediate states for inspection.